# Disable and Enable modules in apache CentOS7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

My goal is to optimize my apache server. At first I want to disable some modules on it. I was surfing over the Internet and didn't find anything dedicated to apache which is installed on CentOS7. Here are what I have got from surfing: [disable unneeded modules](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-disable-apache-modules-under-linux-unix/),[enable apache modules from the command line](https://serverfault.com/questions/56394/how-do-i-enable-apache-modules-from-the-command-line-in-redhat) and on.
I can list Apache enabled modules using this `httpd -t` command. Also I know that modules that were compiled during the installation is lying in `/etc/httpd/modules` directory.

> So what is the right way of disabling and enabling apache modules on CentOS7?

Comment: Commenting-out (or adding) modules in `httpd.conf` seems the normal way for Red Hat-based systems such as CentOS.

Comment: There is nothing to comment out in httpd.conf file on CentOS7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On CentOS 7, the right way to do it is to go through `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` and find the appropriate conf files with the modules you want to disable. You can also check `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, but you'll have better luck in the `conf.modules.d` folder.

Simply comment them out, reload apache, and you're good to go.

Comment: I don't understand how I can comment something in conf.modules.d folder?And there is nothing to comment out in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file o_O

Comment: Standard apache installations on CentOS 7, using yum, places a folder called /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d folder that has plenty of configuration files that load modules, including /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf.

Comment: It is needed just to rename modules in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`:) That's all! And after `systemctl restart httpd` this module won't work! Thanks a lot for forwarding in right way!

Comment: A comment in this case could be a # character at the beginning of the line that says, "LoadModule ..." if you need an example.

Answer (score 1):

With `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d`, the principles are the same: to disable a module or a configuration file, rename its file extension to something different from `.conf`.

Comment: The problem with renaming the config file to disable a module is that if/when the yum package that created the config file gets updated it will put the original file back in place thus re-enabling the module(s).

Answer (score 0):

I created a small python script to help you with it.
Please have a look at https://github.com/zioalex/unused_apache_modules

This is what you can expect from it:

```
curl http://localhost/server-info > http_modules_test.txt
cat http_modules_test.txt| python find_unused_apache_mod.py

1
Module name mod_python.c
Configuration Phase Participation: 4
Request Phase Participation: 11
Current Configuration: 3

2
Module name mod_version.c
Configuration Phase Participation: 0
Request Phase Participation: 0
Current Configuration: 1

3
Module name mod_proxy_connect.c
Configuration Phase Participation: 0
Request Phase Participation: 0
Current Configuration: 0

To remove safely:
 ['mod_proxy_connect.c']
POPPED:  mod_proxy_connect.c

To KEEP:  ['mod_python.c', 'mod_version.c', 'mod_proxy_connect.c']
```

Answer (score -1):

In Centos 7:

To enable or disable modules, you must check out the files in the folder `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.conf
```

To go directly to the list of enabled modules:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf
```

The file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` contains most of the modules (and `LoadModule` directives)  included with Apache. To disable a module just comment out the particular directive. A `LoadModule` directive looks like the following:

LoadModule status_module "modules/mod_status.so"

You just need to add a `#` before the directive to disable the module and remove the `#` to enable a disabled module. For example commenting out:

```
#LoadModule status_module "modules/mod_status.so"
```

will disable the status module.

- To check out the enabled modules use `httpd -M`
- To check out syntax errors use `httpd -t`
- To check out all the files in the  `conf.modules.d` folder use

  `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.conf`

In Centos 7 you can just comment out the unnecessary modules to disable them. However, there is a different file for the `MPM` modules which are also loaded using `LoadModule` directives in Apache `httpd` server.
If you want to [change the MPM module](https://www.notesmatic.com/change-apache-mpm-in-aws-ec2/), it can be done through

```
 /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
```

Comment: There's really no point answering to that in comments. Your answer came up in the [review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro), so just editing the answer is quite enough :-) Unnecessary comments just confuse things, and take up space - number of comments is limited on purpose. I'm deleting mine as it's served its purpose :-) It's a good idea to check out the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help); best answers are clear and self-contained (i.e. no need to read others to get the point), just like this revised one :-)

Comment: BTW the formatting of your answer will change a bit. I added code brackets for clarity. My edit will become visible once another member of the community approves it.